# CSS for Firefox and Safari on Mac OS?

Tags: css

This might be a stupid question, but I have a scenario where I fixed someone's webpage, and it is looking good on all major web browsers on my Windows machine. However, when I uploaded the website to Adobe BrowserLab, and when I looked at Safari and Firefox on a OS X, the footer is a bit off from Safari and FireFox on a Windows operating system.

My questions are:

- Is there a way to target only Safari and Firefox on OS X and not touching those on a Windows? I mean, is there a way to create a stylesheet only for OS X?
- Or are there any conditional comments (for example, ) that targets Mac OS X? If not, are there any other ways?
- Or, am I F out of luck?

Thank you people!

Comment: Generally there is no such issues if you use a CSS reset. The problem is probably in your initial CSS - some margins, paddings, floats etc. might give you that small difference in output

Comment: Well, I'm going to look over the code again and see if there are any floats, paddings, or floats issues, which probably are because who made the website in the first place decided to style the website in the HTML document and using CSS as well.

Answer (score 2):

Best practice:  Try to fix it without doing user agent detection. Analyze the problem, you could try to ask specific advice on your problem here. Especially Gecko and WebKit rendering engines behave almost exactly the same on each platform, bugs should be easy to squash.

If you **really** can't fix it, you can do JS browser detection, and include a CSS dynamically.

- detect: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html
- insert css: http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Howto_Dynamically_Insert_Javascript_And_CSS

This is a bad practice however: whenever you make changes, you need to change each css for each browser.

Comment: You should not have to use javascript for this

Comment: @DominicGreen : JS detection is better than CSS hacks: it relies on documented, specified behavior, instead of a hack which could cause trouble in other or later browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You can target browsers specifically normally firefox chrome etc work roughly the same and ie may work slightly differently.

A way to target browsers is described here

http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/browser-specific_css_hacks/
 http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/conditionalcomments

Comment: Saying that there normally is a way to do this without having to resort to this.

Comment: If I do something like this(<!--[if !IE]><!--><link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />      
<!--<![endif]-->) this will target all browsers except IE, but it won't know the difference between a Windows and OS X. Do you see what I'm trying to say?

Comment: Best thing to do here is to show us what is looking different and we can try and fix it rather having to go down this route ;)

Comment: Dominic Green, do you have Adobe BrowserLab?

Comment: No we use virtual machines to cross browser test

Comment: Nevermind, I have found the problem. Instead of text-align: center, it was align: center. Thanks for your help Dominic!

Comment: he he like we said if you had posted your code to look at we could off sorted this more quickly without going down this route. Good luck with the rest off the project

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to target specific browsers but also operating systems for the browser.

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/navigator.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but this is rarely the right approach. I'd imagine that it's a font issue - perhaps you are using a font that is only on Windows, or one where the OSX version is slightly different.

If you did want to do this, you could either use a server side language (for instance, PHP) to check the user agent, then include an extra style sheet, or use JS to add the styles using the same technique.

When researching this, any info on CSS hacks should be avoided at all costs.

This is a good way to do this: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html as it avoids hacks, and produces an easy to use object containing the relevant information.

I would only use this technique in dire situations - in all the sites I've ever made, I've never had to do this, other than for old IE and iOS.